# What's wrong with my code (Need help fixing)

Tags: c++, arrays, random, matrix, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to create a square matrix of random integer numbers of size N=6. For example, for N=4 a possible matrix would be:

```
1 4 9 3
6 3 9 3
4 5 1 2
0 1 3 4
```

Then I would sort and store back the numbers into the matrix filling each row:

```
0 1 1 1
2 3 3 3
3 4 4 4
5 6 9 9
```

I've written some code, but still getting a small amount of errors regarding generating the random numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

const size_t N = 6;
const int MIN_VAL = 10;
const int MAX_VAL = 99;

unsigned random(double rangeMin, double rangeMax);
void print2d(int **, size_t, size_t);
void selectionSort2d(int **, size_t, size_t);

void selectionSort2d(int **a, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    size_t minX, minY, x = 0, y = 0, i, k;
    int t;

    while (x < rows) {
        minX = x; minY = y;
        i = x; if ((k = (y+1) % cols) == 0) ++i;
        while (i < rows) {
            while (k < cols) {
                if (a[i][k] < a[minX][minY]) {
                    minX = i; minY = k;
                }
                ++k;
            }
            ++i; k = 0;
        }
        t = a[minX][minY];
        a[minX][minY] = a[x][y];
        a[x][y] = t;

        if ((y = (y + 1) % cols) == 0) ++x;
    }
}

void print2d(int **a, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    cout << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            cout << setw(3) << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

unsigned random(double rangeMin, double rangeMax) {
    double maxN;
    assert(rangeMin <= rangeMax);
    maxN = rangeMax - rangeMin + 1;
    return (unsigned)(((rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) * maxN) + rangeMin);
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int **intArray;
    time_t t;

    // Allocate
    intArray = new int*[N];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        intArray[i] = new int[N];
    }

    // Randomize
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            intArray[i][j] = random(MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL);
        }
    }

    // Display
    cout << endl << "Random:";
    print2d(intArray, N, N);

    // Sort
    selectionSort2d(intArray, N, N);

    // Display
    cout << "Sorted:";
    print2d(intArray, N, N);

    // Free
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        delete [] intArray[i];
    }
    delete [] intArray;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what errors do you get? what have you tried?

Comment: I get 3 errors. Line 55: error 'rand' was not declared in this scope. Line 55: error 'RAND_MAX' was not declared in this scope. Line 69: error 'srand' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: I ran your codes, and it works fine. No errors.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just forgot to include cstdlib which was needed to use rand. Been awake for too long :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might need to

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: Thank you. I almost can't believe I forgot to include cstdlib. >_<